# What does this operator do in c++?

Tags: c++

What does `:` do in C++?
is there any difference with `? :`
is it an operator?
for example in code below:

```
    //  Extracting the coefficients and exponents as numbers
    int expon[21] = { 0 };
    int coeff[21] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < monoms; ++i)
    {
        int monomSize = monomStr[i].size();
        for (int j = 0; j < monomSize; ++j)
        {
            if (monomStr[i][j] == '^')
            {
                expon[i] = stoi(monomStr[i].substr(j + 1, monomSize - j));
                coeff[i] = stod(monomStr[i].substr(0, j));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //  Looking for the max of exponents    
    int maxExponent = 0;
    for (int k : expon)                            // <---- **** this colon  ****
        if (k >= maxExponent) maxExponent = k;

    //  Generating the monomials of the null polynomial having 21ree = maxEponent
    std::string newMonom[21];
```

Comment: No it's a range based for loop. It loops through the array `expon` from beginning to end setting `k` to each element of `expon`.

Comment: If you mean `for (int k : expon)` it's range-for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every use of colon (":") in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635535/every-use-of-colon-in-c)

Comment: See: [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop.

Comment: @XXX_fam_XXX You linked an answer about [tag:c]. C++ added some additional usages of colon (e.g. the start of the initializer lists in constructors or just the range loop the OP asked for) which don't exist in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?:` syntax is called the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/758849/10957435), or also sometimes called [the conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/392932/10957435).

The `:` syntax is called a [range-based loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

As for the differences between the two, the conditional operator is sort of a shorthand for if statements. The range-based loop is (as you might guess) a shorthand of sorts for a loop.

Answer (score 7):

It is important to recognize the difference between an "operator" and a just piece of syntax that happens to be punctuation. Operators act on expressions to perform some effect that generates a new expression. `;` is never an operator; it is simply syntax that specifies when a statement or declaration is over. `+` is an operator; it acts on two expressions to produce a new one.

Some symbols can be operators in some places but not others. `<` is an operator... except when the thing right before it is a template-name or the keyword `template`. In that case, it introduces a set of template arguments/parameters bounded by a closing `>`.

`:` is never an operator (even in `?:`, it simply acts as the separator between two terms in the ternary expression); it is simply syntax that serves some role in a piece of grammar. In [range-based `for` statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), it separates the declaration for the variable the loop will generate from the range expression that will do the generation. It could have been a keyword, but C++ is kind of allergic to adding new keywords and prefers to use punctuation where possible.